# Submit dynamics form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have many dynamic created forms (form_for) with check_box elements. I need to create an on click submit. When i click on a checkbox it submits the first form on the page, not the current click form. How can I submit current click form?

```
<%= form_for todo, url: update_todos_path, remote: true, html: { id: 'todo_status'} do |t| %>
                <%= t.text_field :id %>
                <%= t.check_box :isCompleted, {}, 'false', 'true' %>
                <div class='checkbox_text'>
                  <%= todo.text %>
                </div>
```

This jQuery code I use for static forms:

```
$('.checkbox_text').click(function (event) {
 $('#todo_status').submit();
});
```

Also, how can I put param my `:id` without `t.text_field`?

Comment: Have you tried `$(codument).on('click','.checkbox_text',function (event)`

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen didn't work :(

Comment: Do you get any `console` errors? hit F12

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the checkox is inside the form with no element between then, you just need to check for the parent of the checkbox:

```
$('.checkbox_text').click(function (event) {
  $(this).parent().submit(); // $(this).parent() would return the form itself
});
```

When you put an id to an element, this means it is unique. You can't have lots of elements in the dom with the same id an hope to select all of them.

Comment: Thank you. It's work great. 
Maybe you also know about this: `Also, how can I put param my :id without t.text_field `?

Answer (score 0):

You can try $(selector).closest() to get the form from the text.

```
$(document).on('click','.checkbox_text',function (event){
    $(this).closest('#formId').submit() // You can use class name also like('.formClass')
})
```